# Code fails to accurately identify multi-word terms, causing false positives

Tags: python, localization

My issue is with the terms containing 2 or more words. I'm facing a current implementation's inability to accurately match such terms.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load Checker and Terminology DataFrames
checker_df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Checker.xlsx', header=None)
terminology_df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Terminology.xlsx')

# Add a new column for the result and initialize with 'FAIL'
checker_df['Result'] = 'FAIL'

# Iterate over rows in the Checker DataFrame
for index, row in checker_df.iterrows():
    termA = str(row.iloc[0])  # Convert to string and handle NaN
    termB = str(row.iloc[1])  # Convert to string and handle NaN

    # Check if there is at least one row in the terminology sheet where both terms match
    if any(
        (termA.lower() in str(terminology_df_row.iloc[0]).lower() or str(terminology_df_row.iloc[0]).lower() in termA.lower()) and
        (termB.lower() in str(terminology_df_row.iloc[1]).lower() or str(terminology_df_row.iloc[1]).lower() in termB.lower())
        for _, terminology_df_row in terminology_df.iterrows()
    ):
        checker_df.at[index, 'Result'] = 'PASS'

# Save the result to Excel without styling
checker_df.to_excel('C:\\Result.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False, header=['Term A', 'Term B', 'Result'], na_rep='')
```

I'l try to be the more clear as possible about my goal. I need to check possible issues with official terminology terms for English and other languages.

I have two excel files. One named Terminology that it's my reference, and one named Checker where I'll put the English text in column A and the translations in column B and after running the script, I'll have the result in column C.

In my terminology file I have for example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| PS5™ console | console PS5™ |
| button | botão |
| triangle button | botão triângulo |
| console | console |
| eject button | botão de ejeção |
| PlayStation®5 digital edition console | console PlayStation®5 edição digital |

and in my Checker file I have:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| PS5™ console | condsole PSd5 |
| I have a PS5™ console | Eu tenho console PS5™ |
| PS5™ console | console |
| button | botão |
| Botão | botão |
| triangle button | botão |

This is my result file:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PS5™ console | condsole PSd5 | FAIL |
| I have a PS5™ console | Eu tenho console PS5™ | PASS |
| PS5™ console | console | PASS |
| button | botão | PASS |
| Botão | botão | FAIL |
| triangle button | botão | PASS |

My issue is, on the 3rd line, I should have fail. The term is not fully matching the term from the terminology file. Same for the last row, it seems my code pass if only one word is matching for terms with 2 or more words or is because I have similar terms like: button or console. I'm a beginner, I have no idea how to fix this.

I need that the full term matches, and the term can be found in the middle of a bigger text in the checker sheet, this seems to be working well.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you